# How to make unity set window properties (sticky, on top) to some windows (google talk)

Tags: unity, window-manager, usability

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and I would like to the default Window Manager to help me setting "Always on Top" and "Always on Visible Workspace" properties to some windows.  Ideally matching the title with some regular expressions.

I would like to keep the Window Manager, (I know there are others), since I am used to it, I like for most of the things and I configured some settings to my tastes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://wiki.compiz.org/WindowMatching, a specific ["on top" example](http://techspalace.blogspot.de/2008/06/compiz-and-windows-rules.html), as well as a similar [Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126233/how-to-set-a-shortcut-for-always-on-top-for-window) (for reference):

- one way would be to [install](http://www.howtogeek.com/101006/how-to-tweak-unity-on-ubuntu-with-the-compizconfig-settings-manager/) `CCSM`,
- learn to (regex) identify your window,
- and finally use `CCSM`'s **Window Rules** plugin (as described in more detail in the links above) to achieve your goal.

Note that `CCSM` should be [handled with care](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1915533.html) (or be avoided altogether).

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!  (not with regex, however, but with substrings; less elegant but good enough for me)