# Is it possible to put active window in background?

Tags: gnome, window-management

A feature that was useful to me was the ability to have the active window in background.

For instance, you may want to have a small window in foreground while typing on libreoffice in full screen.

Back in the 90's this was a common feature of CDE or OLWM.

Is there a way to obtain similar behavior in Gnome?

Answer (score 2):

If I right click the title bar, I can select "Always On Top". This allows me to have a window remain floating on top of a libre office, or gedit, etc. so I can reference the top, while focus remaining on what I want behind. You may find [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126233/how-to-set-a-shortcut-for-always-on-top-for-window) thread useful, and there are quite a few other solutions if right clicking does not work for you.

Answer (score 1):

XFCE and Gnome will allow you to do so so with the "Always on top" option. It is not "setting the active window to the background", but forcing a window to stay in foreground, even if it has lost its focus.

[image]

Gnome has the same feature as described [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/keep-a-window-always-on-top-linux/) by right clicking the context menu. This is the result (terminal is on top while working in nautilus):

[image]