Disable "Always on Top" in Google Chrome
Google Chrome [Version 129.0.6668.70 (Official Build) (64-bit)] on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is weirdly fixed at Always on Top. Unchecking the option is not functioning. How can I disable it?
The solutions (https://askubuntu.com/a/511077/947071, https://superuser.com/a/1329306/1024595) didn't work in my case. It appears that the option Always on Top can't be unchecked from my end.
$ apt-cache policy google-chrome-stable
google-chrome-stable:
  Installed: 129.0.6668.70-1
  Candidate: 129.0.6668.70-1
  Version table:
 *** 129.0.6668.70-1 500
        500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

I use the Gnome extension Forge for tiling window manager. Google Chrome is not functioning according to tiling settings. I wasn't facing this issue two days ago. Is it because of their recent update or is something due to my system? I like to understand what is causing it.

Here's the dpkg upgrade logs since 2024-09-18:
$ sudo zgrep -h "upgrade " /var/log/dpkg.log* | awk '$1 >= "2024-09-18"' | sort -r | less
2024-10-01 13:27:53 upgrade cloud-init:all 24.3.1-0ubuntu0~24.04.1 24.3.1-0ubuntu0~24.04.2
2024-10-01 12:14:19 upgrade xxd:amd64 2:9.1.0016-1ubuntu7.2 2:9.1.0016-1ubuntu7.3
2024-10-01 12:14:18 upgrade vim-common:all 2:9.1.0016-1ubuntu7.2 2:9.1.0016-1ubuntu7.3
2024-10-01 12:14:17 upgrade vim-tiny:amd64 2:9.1.0016-1ubuntu7.2 2:9.1.0016-1ubuntu7.3
2024-09-30 11:01:31 upgrade fastfetch:amd64 2.25.0 2.26.1ubuntu1
2024-09-27 11:03:46 upgrade xdg-desktop-portal:amd64 1.18.4-1ubuntu2 1.18.4-1ubuntu2.24.04.1
2024-09-27 11:03:45 upgrade gnome-shell-common:all 46.0-0ubuntu6~24.04.4 46.0-0ubuntu6~24.04.5
2024-09-27 11:03:43 upgrade gnome-shell:amd64 46.0-0ubuntu6~24.04.4 46.0-0ubuntu6~24.04.5
2024-09-27 11:03:42 upgrade gnome-shell-extension-prefs:amd64 46.0-0ubuntu6~24.04.4 46.0-0ubuntu6~24.04.5
2024-09-27 11:03:41 upgrade mutter-common-bin:amd64 46.2-1ubuntu0.24.04.1 46.2-1ubuntu0.24.04.2
2024-09-27 11:03:40 upgrade libmutter-14-0:amd64 46.2-1ubuntu0.24.04.1 46.2-1ubuntu0.24.04.2
2024-09-27 11:03:38 upgrade gir1.2-mutter-14:amd64 46.2-1ubuntu0.24.04.1 46.2-1ubuntu0.24.04.2
2024-09-27 11:03:36 upgrade mutter-common:all 46.2-1ubuntu0.24.04.1 46.2-1ubuntu0.24.04.2
2024-09-27 10:42:48 upgrade cloud-init:all 24.2-0ubuntu1~24.04.2 24.3.1-0ubuntu0~24.04.1
2024-09-27 10:42:47 upgrade cups-browsed:amd64 2.0.0-0ubuntu10 2.0.0-0ubuntu10.1
2024-09-27 10:42:46 upgrade libppd2:amd64 2:2.0.0-0ubuntu4 2:2.0.0-0ubuntu4.1
2024-09-27 10:42:45 upgrade libppd2-common:all 2:2.0.0-0ubuntu4 2:2.0.0-0ubuntu4.1
2024-09-27 10:42:44 upgrade libcupsfilters2t64:amd64 2.0.0-0ubuntu7 2.0.0-0ubuntu7.1
2024-09-27 10:42:43 upgrade libcupsfilters2-common:all 2.0.0-0ubuntu7 2.0.0-0ubuntu7.1
2024-09-27 10:42:42 upgrade libcups2t64:amd64 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.2 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.3
2024-09-27 10:42:41 upgrade libcupsimage2t64:amd64 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.2 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.3
2024-09-27 10:42:40 upgrade cups:amd64 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.2 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.3
2024-09-27 10:42:38 upgrade cups-daemon:amd64 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.2 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.3
2024-09-27 10:42:37 upgrade cups-server-common:all 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.2 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.3
2024-09-27 10:42:36 upgrade cups-ppdc:amd64 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.2 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.3
2024-09-27 10:42:35 upgrade cups-core-drivers:amd64 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.2 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.3
2024-09-27 10:42:34 upgrade cups-client:amd64 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.2 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.3
2024-09-27 10:42:33 upgrade cups-bsd:amd64 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.2 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.3
2024-09-27 10:42:31 upgrade cups-common:all 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.2 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.3
2024-09-27 10:42:30 upgrade cups-ipp-utils:amd64 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.2 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.3
2024-09-26 16:21:40 upgrade libopenjp2-7:amd64 2.5.0-2build3 2.5.0-2ubuntu0.1
2024-09-25 19:35:06 upgrade update-manager:all 1:24.04.6 1:24.04.8
2024-09-25 19:35:05 upgrade update-manager-core:all 1:24.04.6 1:24.04.8
2024-09-25 19:35:04 upgrade python3-update-manager:all 1:24.04.6 1:24.04.8
2024-09-25 09:11:42 upgrade intel-microcode:amd64 3.20240813.0ubuntu0.24.04.2 3.20240910.0ubuntu0.24.04.1
2024-09-25 09:01:30 upgrade google-chrome-stable:amd64 129.0.6668.58-1 129.0.6668.70-1
2024-09-24 19:24:56 upgrade linux-firmware:amd64 20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.3 20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.4
2024-09-20 20:26:15 upgrade fastfetch:amd64 2.24.0 2.25.0
2024-09-20 07:56:57 upgrade ubuntu-pro-client:amd64 33.2~24.04.1 34~24.04
2024-09-20 07:56:55 upgrade ubuntu-pro-client-l10n:amd64 33.2~24.04.1 34~24.04
2024-09-19 19:55:51 upgrade ubuntu-settings:all 24.04.4 24.04.5
2024-09-19 19:55:49 upgrade apparmor:amd64 4.0.1really4.0.0-beta3-0ubuntu0.1 4.0.1really4.0.1-0ubuntu0.24.04.3
2024-09-19 19:55:47 upgrade systemd-hwe-hwdb:all 255.1.3 255.1.4
2024-09-19 19:55:46 upgrade libapparmor1:amd64 4.0.1really4.0.0-beta3-0ubuntu0.1 4.0.1really4.0.1-0ubuntu0.24.04.3
2024-09-19 19:54:23 upgrade procps:amd64 2:4.0.4-4ubuntu3 2:4.0.4-4ubuntu3.1
2024-09-19 19:54:21 upgrade libproc2-0:amd64 2:4.0.4-4ubuntu3 2:4.0.4-4ubuntu3.1
2024-09-19 06:14:44 upgrade qbittorrent:amd64 1:4.6.6.99~202409161207-8149-bb0fcc584~ubuntu24.04.1 1:4.6.7.99~202409181207-8154-a869e4151~ubuntu24.04.1
2024-09-19 06:14:38 upgrade firefox:amd64 130.0+build2-0ubuntu0.24.04.1~mt1 130.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.24.04.1~mt1
2024-09-18 07:00:40 upgrade google-chrome-stable:amd64 128.0.6613.137-1 129.0.6668.58-1
(END)



where you can see:
2024-09-25 09:01:30 upgrade google-chrome-stable:amd64 129.0.6668.58-1 129.0.6668.70-1
2024-09-18 07:00:40 upgrade google-chrome-stable:amd64 128.0.6613.137-1 129.0.6668.58-1

If I remember correctly, I didn't face this issue up to the google-chrome-stable:amd64 129.0.6668.58-1. So, I just checked by downgrading to the versions 129.0.6668.58-1 and 128.0.6613.137-1. But its behavior stayed the same.

The issue seems to be happening due to the GNOME extension Forge (https://github.com/forge-ext/forge/issues/426). The behavior disappears when the extension is turned off.
What would be the solution to fix this issue in Forge? Also, I would like to know if it is possible to get the same auto-tilting config with the native Ubuntu Tiling Assistant.

I assume you can just right click the top bar and uncheck Always on Top.
Also you can try this hotkey to disable always on top: https://askubuntu.com/a/511077/1956088

It is not working. Check my updated question.
